# Cannot plot with matplolib with non-ascii chars on title

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot a set of pie charts but my strings on plot titles are in Turkish and include non-ascii chars in string type. As I try to plot, matplotlib raises following error with this by this line;

```
pylab.title(title_str)
pylab.savefig('figure1') # raises error

matplotlib display text must have all code points < 128 or use Unicode strings.
```

If I try to encode title_str to unicode it also gives;

```
pylab.title(match.encode('utf-8'))
pylab.savefig('erogol')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I can use 'ignore' setting with encode() but I must write all titles without any missing character. Is there any way to correct this problem?

Comment: The data should be decoded from an encoding when it enters the program. At that point it is Unicode. And it should be passed as Unicode to `pylab.title()`

Comment: Also you may want to import ``unicode_literals`` from ``__future__`` [Matplotlib unicdoe demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/unicode_demo.html)

Comment: I appended import statement to the beginning of file but it does not work with the same errors

Comment: Have you tried LaTeX markup?  Also, could you provide a sample of the `title_str` so options can be tested.

Comment: How about providing a minimal example to reproduce the error?